# How to expand all nodes that has a children on page load by default in wix angular tree control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree

Has anybody tried to expand all nodes that has a children on page load by default in tree created by angular tree control. It is packed with lots of features but lacks this one. It is having an expanded nodes property. So do we need to find the array of nodes that has children by some other logic and has to pass the same to expanded nodes? Is that the correct logic or am i missing any inbuilt functionality in the directive? Please help

http://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/

Answer (score 1):

In order to load the nodes expanded, you have to create a list of node objects which should be expanded by default and pass it to expanded-nodes attribute in html

Controller Script as:

```
    $scope.dataForTheTree = [{
        text: "Data Sources",
        children: [{
            text: "Hard Drive Health",
            children: []
        }]
    }, {
        text: "Diagrams",
        children: [{
            text: "Hard Drive Failure Example",
            children: []
        }]
    }];

    $scope.expandedNodes = [vm.dataForTheTree[0],vm.dataForTheTree[1]];
```

HTML Element as:

```
 <treecontrol class="tree-classic" tree-model="dataForTheTree" expanded-nodes="expandedNodes">
                    {{node.text}}
                </treecontrol>
```